# Add a printer to LPT port and send file to it in C#

Tags: c#, printing, zebra-printers

I have a command shell script that installs a printer (it's Zebra printer if that matters) on LPT port (the printer itself is connected through USB) and sends a file to it which triggers the actual printing. Then the printer is removed from the port

```
net use lpt1: \\MyComputer\MyPrinter
copy D:\Test\Printout.epl lpt1
net use lpt1: /delete
```

How can I do the same using C# code?

Comment: Simplest: with `Process.Start()` for 1st and 3d line and `File.Copy()` for 2nd one.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: This requires pinvoke.  You need at least WNetAddConnection2() and WNetCancelConnection().  The copy ought to be problematic since .NET normally rejects device names so I'd expect File.Copy() to fail.  Pinvoke CopyFile().  Using a .cmd file is certainly the lower pain point but the error checking is going to be miserable.  What you probably *really* want to do is not use a file, use [this code](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091) instead.  Asking the vendor for help is reasonable, you are not the first C# programmer trying to use a Zebra printer.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void PrintFile(string path) {
string strCmdText = "/c copy " + path + " LPT1";
Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText); }
```