# Send text file to Shared Printer

Tags: vb.net, printing, barcode-printing, network-printers, zpl-ii

I have a VB program which creates a barcode layout and information using ZPL, then saves this to a txt file then I use File.Copy to copy the text file from the save location to the Zebra Printer, this works perfect with the printer that is directly connected to the workstation with the program installed, however i am trying to use the same printer for multiple workstations as we don't need 1 printer per workstation (ideally). I have "Shared" the printer on the installed workstation (connection via USB) and i am able to see and setup the share on the other workstations so it shows in the workstations printer list (so i know the computer can see the share), however when i try File.Copy(TextFileLocation,\SHARECOMP\ZebraPrinterShareName i get an "Access to path \SHARECOMP\ZebraPrinterShareName is denied" error.

Is there a way to be able to send this file to the shared printer within my VB Program or something i need to do to allow the copy to happen and remove the access denied error?

Many Thanks for any advice

Comment: Did you make sure you authenticate properly against the target machine (in this case `SHARECOMP`)?

Comment: Another option, depending on the actual zebra printer.  Think a few of the higher end ones have an inbuilt ftp to upload files too.  Although being connected by usb may put the stoppers on this

Comment: @Sideways In what way do i authenticate against the Target Machine? I have the share in the printer list, but i am just trying the simple File.Copy to move the file?

Comment: You authenticate via normal Windows authentication, for instance, you can invoke `WNetAddConnection2` to connect to a Windows machine and establish a connection. I just wanted to make sure you have access to the machine, as this seems to be the error cause. If you have, I assume you can copy files via Windows Explorer to the folder?

Comment: You could give the spooler API a try...

Answer (score 0):

The [UNC path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats#unc-paths) to the share name doesn't look correct.  UNC paths in Windows should start with 2 backslash characters as in:

```
\\SHARECOMP\ZebraPrinterShareName
```

If changing your UNC path to start with 2 backslash characters doesn't work, you can try mapping the shared printer to an LPT port using the "net use" command from a Windows command prompt.

```
net use lpt3 \\SHARECOMP\ZebraPrinterShareName /PERSISTENT:YES
```

After running this command, you can reference the mapped LPT port in your copy command:

```
File.Copy(TextFileLocation,LPT3)
```

Comment: Yea that was a typo on my part from the \\ I will give the NET USE a try and let you know how it goes. I know I have access to the shared printer as I can add it to the local printer list.

Comment: I have managed to do NET USE and that came back as Successful, however how do i reference the LPT3 in the File.Copy in the VB Program as if i enter it as you have, LPT3 isn't declared or referenced to anything so it won't build and if i enclose it in "" it still doesn't understand what "LPT3" is? i have tried to run copy C:\FilePath LPT3 and i get an Access Denied response.

Comment: LPT is a "line printer" device.  It's a legacy port type.  Try referencing as LPT3: as in File.Copy(TextFileLocation, "LPT3:").  If that doesn't work, you can try copying to the LPT3 port using the method described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836180/add-a-printer-to-lpt-port-and-send-file-to-it-in-c-sharp